# .Htaccess redirect index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I transfered an old bulletin board to q2a.org. Now i have a lot index.php files in google which do as 200 OK Status. How can I redirect those links to root? ex. www.domain.com/index.php?page=Board&boardID=14 or www.domain.com/index.php?page=Thread&postID=58585

This is my current .htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
# Redirect non-www to www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just after `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=[^&]+&postID=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I've added this also: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=[^&]+&boardID=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]